# How do I encourage readers of my genealogy blog to get in touch?

Tags: sharing, publishing

I am running a small genealogy blog. Most content is targeted at local historians and genealogists.

It is a low-frequency blog and attracts around 500 readers a month. At the end of my articles, I regularly ask my readers for additions and corrections.

However, there is almost no feedback. The comment section is rarely used. I got a few “thank you“ comments. Once, someone corrected an erroneous entry. A few readers asked me by mail for answers to research problems completely unrelated to my areas of research ("Hello, I am looking for my ancestors in Prague. Thanks.").

I know that my content is helpful to a part of my readers. They download files, look through image collections and read more than just one article.

How can I encourage them to get in touch, share information and contacts?

Answer (score 4):

If your blog is targeted at local historians and genealogists, get ahold of your local history and genealogy groups and make them aware of your blog and to tell their members. They will come back if you have new or interesting content for them, and they will comment as well if something tweaks their interest.

Remember that the world sees your blog. Lots of people will find it who aren't interested in your local history, so don't be offended if they don't post.

Comments happen if you give people something worth commenting about. Think about your content.

Advertise your blog in your email signature and on any profiles you have (such as [your Stack Exchange profile](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/users/834/lejonet))

Finally, [suggest your blog to GeneaBloggers](http://www.geneabloggers.com/suggest-blog/), and support the genealogy blogging community by visiting their blogs and commenting on their posts.